# How to use subqueries in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, syntax, plsql, sys-refcursor

I have the following table:

```
table1
-------------------------
 date      |  ID  | name
-------------------------
 13-jul-15 |   1  |  abc
 13-jul-15 |   2  |  abc
 14-jul-15 |   1  |  def
 13-jul-15 |   3  |  abc
 15-jul-15 |   3  |  def
 ...
```

What I want to do is match the ID and represent as below:

```
 date1     | name | date2     | name | ID 
------------------------------------------ 
 13-jul-15 | abc  | 14-jul-15 | def  | 1   
 13-jul-15 | abc  |           |      | 2  
 13-jul-15 | abc  | 15-jul-15 | def  | 3
 ...
```

I have used the following code, but not getting the result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_details ( oresults1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT *
    FROM ((SELECT date, ID FROM table1 WHERE name= "abc") T1
           UNION ALL
          (SELECT date, ID FROM table1 WHERE name= "def") T2 
         )
   WHERE T1.ID= T2.ID
   ORDER BY ID;
END;
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You want a join not a union all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
with table1 as (select to_date('13/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 id, 'abc' name from dual union all
                select to_date('13/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 id, 'abc' name from dual union all
                select to_date('14/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 id, 'def' name from dual union all
                select to_date('13/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 id, 'abc' name from dual union all
                select to_date('15/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 id, 'def' name from dual)
-- end of mimicking your table1. See below for the query
select t1.dt date1,
       t1.name name1,
       t2.dt date2,
       t2.name name2,
       t1.id
from   table1 t1
       left outer join table1 t2 on (t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = 'abc' and t2.name = 'def')
where  t1.name = 'abc'
order by t1.id;

DATE1      NAME1 DATE2      NAME2         ID
---------- ----- ---------- ----- ----------
13/07/2015 abc   14/07/2015 def            1
13/07/2015 abc                             2
13/07/2015 abc   15/07/2015 def            3

with table1 as (select to_date('13/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 id, 'abc' name from dual union all
                select to_date('13/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 id, 'abc' name from dual union all
                select to_date('14/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 id, 'def' name from dual union all
                select to_date('13/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 id, 'abc' name from dual union all
                select to_date('15/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 3 id, 'def' name from dual)
-- end of mimicking your table1. See below for the query
select t1.dt date1,
       t1.name name1,
       t2.dt date2,
       t2.name name2,
       t1.id
from   (select id, dt, name from table1 where name = 'abc') t1
       left outer join (select id, dt, name from table1 where name = 'def') t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
where  t1.name = 'abc'
order by t1.id;

DATE1      NAME1 DATE2      NAME2         ID
---------- ----- ---------- ----- ----------
13/07/2015 abc   14/07/2015 def            1
13/07/2015 abc                             2
13/07/2015 abc   15/07/2015 def            3
```

Comment: how can i display the date using `to_char(date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: You've kind of answered your own question there? you'd just replace the "date" part of `to_char(date` with whatever date column (or variable) you need converting into that format. E.g. in my queries above, you might change `t1.dt date1` to `to_char(t1.dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date1`

Comment: when I do this:
`select t1.dt date1,
       t1.name name1,
       t2.dt date2,
       t2.name name2,
       t1.id
from   table1 t1
       left outer join table1 t2 on (t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = 'abc' and t2.name = 'def')
where  t1.date1 between TO_DATE('13-Jun-2015 13:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE(13-Jun-2015 13:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS)
order by date1;`

I don't seem to get the records. Is there something wrong in what I am doing?

Comment: I have also changed `t1.dt date1` to `to_char(t1.dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date1` as indicated.

Comment: the sample data you gave only had the date specified, so the time element would default to midnight - ie. 13-Jun-2015 00:00:00. Does that help explain why you're not seeing any results, assuming you're using the same sample data?

Comment: yes, but doesn't altering the same to the above mentioned format result in the required result?

Comment: You seem to be confusing changing the display format of dates with filtering results based on a date range. If you filter your results - e.g. `where t1.date1 between TO_DATE('13-Jun-2015 13:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE(13-Jun-2015 13:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS)` (which, btw, is equivaltent to `where t1.date1 = TO_DATE('13-Jun-2015 13:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`) - you're changing which rows are displayed. By using `to_char()` on the date columns in the select, you're merely changing how the date is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I am querying for between a time frame in which date and time are considered.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use pivot function available in Oracle

```
WITH table_(date#, id#, name#) AS 
(SELECT to_date('13-jul-15', 'dd-mon-yy'), 1,  'abc' FROM dual UNION all 
 SELECT to_date('13-jul-15', 'dd-mon-yy'), 2,  'abc' FROM dual UNION all
 SELECT to_date('14-jul-15', 'dd-mon-yy'), 1,  'def' FROM dual UNION all
 SELECT to_date('13-jul-15', 'dd-mon-yy'), 3,  'abc' FROM dual UNION all
 SELECT to_date('15-jul-15', 'dd-mon-yy'), 3,  'def' FROM dual)
--------
-- End of data preparation
--------
SELECT * 
  FROM table_
 PIVOT (MIN(date#) AS date#, MIN(name#) AS NAME# FOR name# IN ('abc' AS ABC, 'def' AS DEF));
```

Output

```
| ID# |              ABC_DATE# | ABC_NAME# |              DEF_DATE# | DEF_NAME# |
|-----|------------------------|-----------|------------------------|-----------|
|   1 | July, 13 2015 00:00:00 |       abc | July, 14 2015 00:00:00 |       def |
|   2 | July, 13 2015 00:00:00 |       abc |                        |           |
|   3 | July, 13 2015 00:00:00 |       abc | July, 15 2015 00:00:00 |       def |
```